# How can I cancel an in-flight Requests.Session.Get request?

Tags: python, sockets, python-requests

So I have a helper thread that listens for info from a server using https.  I'm using Python's Requests.Session and calling get() with no timeout because we do want to wait for some response.

However, at shutdown, I want to nicely end all my helper threads.  I'm not sure how to kill the get request which the thread is blocking on.  On *nix environments closing the underlying socket for the session will end up throwing up an exception.  So thats a way to do this; close socket, catch exception, be happy.  On Windows this doesn't seem to work tho.

What is the right way to kill/end the session and the get request so that my helper thread can die?

Clarification:
I'm using Python's Requests.Session.get().

Comment: I believe if you're using a `requests.session()` object, you can just call `sess.close()`, which ought to do the right thing. You could also send a signal, but that's also Unix-only. Then again, you could just kill the threads and/or quit and let the OS do it…

Comment: Actually, I just tested, and `sess.close()` doesn't actually close any open requests. So never mind that part.

Comment: Yea, sess.close doesn't do the right thing (at least not the thing I want).  Closing the socket (you have to access protected vars to get the socket) will do it on *nix but apparently not Win.

Comment: Another idea: Pass `prefetch=False`, and have your thread loop around checking for shutdown or trying to read from `response.raw`. I haven't looked at `urllib3`; if it doesn't have some way to async read, you'd have to go down a level to `http`, and maybe even to `socket` (plus `select`), at which point you might as well not be using `requests` in the first place.

Comment: Yup, I wanted to keep using Requests (if possible) so that I don't have to write all that + parsing + all the other code path bits.

Comment: Honestly, looking through the free functions and the members of the response and session objects, I don't think `requests` has any way to cancel requests. Is there a reason just killing the threads or letting the OS do it isn't acceptable? (You want to make sure the probably-unresponsive server gets a clean shutdown on the socket for some reason?) If so, maybe you should consider using a different library, like one of the cURL wrappers.

Comment: The thread does other work too, cleanup, pushing things around, so I'd prefer to have it end cleanly rather than just murdering it like that.  I think I may need to look into something other than Requests (aww well).

Comment: Hold on… if you use both a `Session` and an explicit `PoolManager` (which means explicitly importing `urllib3` as well as `requests`, but it's not that complicated), does `close` help then? According to http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/, `Session.close()` "… just closes the `PoolManager`, which closes pooled connections." Does that do anything useful?

Comment: To answer my own question… it looks like, if you get this to work, it ultimately comes down to the pool calling a function that closes the socket after any reads complete… meaning it doesn't help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After looking through everything I could think of, it looks like `requests` has no way to cancel an in-flight request without getting all the way down to the socket level. And, as the OP pointed out, even that doesn't help directly on Windows, unless you actually get into the underlying select-or-pool loop instead of just closing the socket. (And if you didn't care about Windows, you could more easily cancel the reads just by `signal`ing the thread…) So, that's pretty much out.

One alternative is to just kill the threads, or let the OS do it for you. If the thread does other work too… well, you *can* always split that off onto different threads. But that could be a major, and unwarranted, rewrite of your code.

So, it sounds like you need to give up `requests` and use something else.

The cURL library definitely has the ability to cancel requests. There's an official set of bindings called [`pycurl`](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/python/), but it's much lower-level than `requests`, so you may want to look over the 69105 higher-level wrappers you can find by searching at [PyPI](http://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3aaction=search&term=curl&submit=search). Some of them are not very complete/stable/up-to-date, so you probably need to do a bit of playing around to find the right one for you…

Comment: "One alternative is to just kill the threads" But... you can't kill threads in Python

Comment: And it seems like you can't signal another thread in Python: "[...] signals can’t be used as a means of inter-thread communication." https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/signal.html#signals-and-threads

Answer (score -1):

You can use Timeouts of python requests, [the documentation](https://2.python-requests.org/en/v2.8.1/user/advanced/#timeouts) explain that you can set a
tuple like (conn_timeout_ms, read_timeout_ms) for timeout parameter:

```
r = requests.get('https://github.com', timeout=(conn_timeout_ms, read_timeout_ms))
```

In this example if after read_timeout_ms you don't get any response from the server the request will be aborted

Comment: Timeouts set how long the library waits for the connection to be made and the first byte to be sent, not the full response time.

Comment: if you request a website that streams SoundCloud for example, this solution doesn't work. Since the connection is could be strong and it answers immediately. Those two parameters just work when the connection is weak or the website answer late or never.